# How to display a random number between 2 numbers in Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am working in Matter.js, and I am not able to display a number between 2 numbers. I want help with what should be the correct code and in which function to write it.

Comment: [rtm](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Common.html#method_choose)

Comment: What does displaying a random numbers between two numbers have to do with Matter.js, a graphics library that simulates physics? Do you mean to ask about JavaScript, the language MJS is built in? Regardless, please show an attempt and some input and output. Are the bounds inclusive or exclusive? Do you want a random integer or a random float? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Please share your code to show what you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in Matter.js but this should work as this is pure javascript.

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum) + minNum;
```